# Convergence of the tail of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Claim: A Sequence converges iff the tail of it converges.

When I was trying to prove this, I feel a lot of troubles from indexing. And I feel like to proving "if a Sequence converges, then the tail of it converges" is trivial. Can anyone give me some suggestions on this proof. Also, I feel the same issue on indexing when proving the converse of it.

What I have tried so far:

Proof:
part 1) if a Sequence converges, then the tail of it converges.

Let sequence $A$ be given. Let $B$ denote the $i$-th tail of it. It is clear that $A(n+i-1)=B(n).$

Now, let $\epsilon >0$ be given. It follows that there exists a natural number $N$ such that

$\begin{align*}\lvert A(n)-L\rvert\ \leq \epsilon \end{align*} $       whenever $n\geq N.$

Now let's choose $N_0=N+i-1.$ Note that

$\begin{align*}\lvert A(N+i-1)-L\rvert\ \leq \epsilon \end{align*} $  since $N+i-1\geq N$

Thus,

$\begin{align*}\lvert B(n)-L\rvert\ \leq \epsilon \end{align*} $ whenever $n\geq N_0.$
it completes part one of the proof.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

**Notes**:

Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary.

On the direction you are trying to prove: Assuming that $i \geq 1$, then if $n \geq N$, you also have $n+i-1 \geq n \geq N$. Therefore, if $N$ is chosen so that $|A(n) - L|  <\epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$, you also get that $|B(n)-L| = |A(n+i-1)-L| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$, since $n+i-1 \geq N$.

For the converse direction, if $N_1$ is chosen so that for all $n \geq N_1$ it holds that $|B(n)-L|<\epsilon$, then try $N = N_1 + i-1$. Indeed, if $n \geq N$, then $n-i+1 \geq N_1$, so $|B(n-i+1)-L| = |A(n)-L| <\epsilon$.

Comment: But in the converse, you have to ensure that n-i+1 is positive, how would you do it?

Comment: If $N_1 \geq 1$ and $N = N_1 + i -1$, then for any $n \geq N$, $n \geq N_1 + i-1 \implies n - i +1 \geq N_1 \geq 1$.